# timeseries analysis with changing correlations between independent and dependent variables

Tags: time-series, correlation

In multivariate timeseries analysis where the correlation between independent variables and the dependent variable changes (different variables have changing explanatory power) over time what methods are typically used to account for the changing relationship aside from reoptimizing?

1. Is there a way to pair the rolling correlation$(x_n, y)$ with the strength of the signal $x_n$ especially in modern machine learning methods?
2. Is the use of regime switching useful (I think this might be difficult if there are a large number of independents due to segmentation)?

Regards

Comment: Is xn supposed to be $x_n$?

Comment: yes thanks for the edit

Comment: This is beyond my expertise and recent but you might look at it. https://www.casact.org/pubs/forum/18spforumv2/06_Korn.pdf

Comment: Although this issue is raised a lot, for example in structural breaks, I have never seen a method to address it aside from the one I posted (which is obviously complex and recent).  I think the common solution is to analyze the data in pieces, during different periods, or to ignore this issue.

Comment: so far my approach has been to look at rolling variance of the dependent time-series and using a clustering algorithm as an unsupervised learner then build regressions on each regime. And test for improved r2 score.